# GUI Problems on setTheme (Glitch) Android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I´m programming an app. We have time so I want to to a darkmode as extra. (Not Day/Night just internal setting) I defined themes with attributes like TextColor which I implemented in my style with ?attr/TextColor.

attrs.xml

```
<resources>
<attr name="TextColor" format="reference" />
<attr name="BackGroundColor" format="reference" />
<attr name="LightTextColor" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/backGround</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="TextColor">@color/strongText</item>
    <item name="BackGroundColor">@color/backGround</item>
    <item name="LightTextColor">@color/lightText</item>
</style>

<style name="DarkMode" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#555555</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="TextColor">@color/backGround</item>
    <item name="BackGroundColor">@color/strongText</item>
    <item name="LightTextColor">@color/lighterText</item>
</style>
```

I do setTheme on each Activity.(stored in pref) Works fine!

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    app = application as ChronoDroidApp
    setTheme(app.selectedTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.actual_shift_ui)
    loadReasons()
}
```

I also use DynamicLayout. I add RadioButtons I need. I set Styles like:

```
var reasonRadioButton = RadioButton(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CheckBox)).apply {
                        text = reason
                    }
reasonRadioGroup.addView(reasonRadioButton)
```

Style:

```
<style name="CheckBox">
    <item name="android:padding">8dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/radio_button</item>
    <item name="android:buttonTint">?attr/TextColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?attr/TextColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?attr/BackGroundColor</item>
</style>
```

(@drawable/radio_button doesn't work for me because I can't set attr in the selector XML, just "android:textColor">?attr/TextColor would be good - I will get that!)
In the Theme style I set this custom attributes. (black/white)

But now, when I setTheme(R.style.DarkMode) it gets ... messed up! (on all dynamic generated layouts)

[image: Glitch DarkMode]

On my normal theme the behaviour is right: (also on dynamic, it's the same):

[image: normal theme]

My concerns are the glitches, it's really strange.
Any ideas why I got misbehaviour?

Comment: Looks like a Fragment with a transparent background, and you used `add` in the transaction instead of `replace` so the previous Fragment is still there and now it's showing through.

Comment: This is not a Fragment, this is an Activity which gets indent, both screens are the same way loaded. Even when I change Theme in my app and go back (prefs) it works on the first Theme and when I switch Theme(DarkMode) (in styles with attr) the behaviour is wrong. fE. choose ExtraInfo ("Sonstige Begründung") it pops up (addView) a EditText but it doesn't expand the layout on Theme Dark Mode. (Glitch)

Comment: ExtraInfo added, just set visibility … (GONE/VISIBLE) … messes up everything on DarkMode

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a Bug ... on an Android 6 (xCover 3) it's fine, on an Android 9 (Nokia 6.1) it get glitches. I develop for API 23.
BUT!!!!

in DarkMode I used HEX for color,

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/strongText</item>
```

solves the problem.

For TextColor for RadioButton I had to do this, I skipped selector, I don'T need it, it's ok with colorAccent

```
  <style name="CheckBox">
    <item name="android:padding">8dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/TextColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?attr/TextColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?attr/BackGroundColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?attr/TextColor</item>
</style>
```

and in Activity

```
var reasonRadioButton = RadioButton(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CheckBox)).apply {
                        text = reason
                        setTextAppearance(R.style.CheckBox)
                    }
```

Comment: Hex are to crappy for new Androidversions, Background was set -> overlay

Comment: I am just a shame: #555555 never worked, just older Versions don't care. #555555 must be look like lightdarkgray not black(no value), as seen on screenshots, I should delete this post, I let  it for quick and dirty ideots, as me!